# show warning before execute sql code

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I do a mistake update in sqlserver and my database be clear. I want add custom warning in Microsoft SQL SERVER software when I press execute button, 
for example if my update code haven't any where at his line the IDE(ms sql server 2014 or any version) show warning to me

Comment: pleas don't give me negative if you don't know how to do it my friend :|

Comment: Please make your question better and more clear instead of asking not to downvote because of your poor question.

Comment: @JamesZ – IMHO using common sense, the question is clear enough and someone was already also able to add valid answer mentioning SQL Prompt. It is often helpful to all parties to ask in comments if some specific aspect of the question is unclear.

Comment: @miroxlav thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make SSMS to do that. You need to use some third party tools and add-on.

Look at SQL Prompt from RedGate or tools from ApexSQL

[SQL Prompt](https://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/94413-sql-prompt/suggestions/6594489-warning-on-delete-and-update-statements-if-no-wher)

[ApexSQL Complete](https://blog.apexsql.com/whats-next-in-apexsql-complete-2017-r6-execution-alerts/)

Comment: tnx alote you help me full

Answer (score 2):

Check this I found a cool feature that can be useful. Not exactly what you are looking for but definitely very useful.

http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-preferred-connections

Comment: tnx Jack James i don't hear about it before now